# continuously in interval sending data from GSM to webserver is not working as expected.

Tags: php, server, gsm, gprs

I am trying to keep sending data in interval of 20 seconds , but instead of sending one record per 20 seconds, two records together getting sent at once in 40 seconds.please suggest if this is usual behaviour with the GPRS or we are missing something.

GSM i am using is GL865 and arduino uno.

Please share your feedback.

And some time it send 3 data after 60 seconds.

```
mySerial.println("AT&K=0");
    smart_delay(2000);
    mySerial.println("AT+CGDCONT=1,\"IP\",\"www\",\"0.0.0.0\",0,0");
    smart_delay(3000);
    mySerial.println("AT#GPRS=1");
    smart_delay(3000);
    mySerial.println("AT+CGPADDR=1");
    smart_delay(3000);
    mySerial.println("AT#SCFG=1,1,300,90,600,250");
    smart_delay(5000);



while(1)
{
        mySerial.println("AT+CREG?");

        mySerial.println("AT#CGPADDR=1");
        smart_delay(4000);

        mySerial.println("AT#SGACT=1,1");                         
        mySerial.println("AT#SD=1,0,80,\"XXXXXXXX.com\"");


            req = "\r\nGET /?func=updateDeviceLoc&params=";               
            req.print(1);
            req+=":"; 
            req.print(flat,6);           
            req+=":";           
            req.print(flon,6);           
            req+=" HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: XXXXXXXXXXXXX.com\r\nConnection:keep-alive\r\n";
            mySerial.println(req);
            smart_delay(20000);

} 




// smart_delay() function .
static void smart_delay(unsigned long ms)
```

{

```
int x=0;
char c;
unsigned long start = millis();
do 
{
    while (mySerial.available())
    {
        c=mySerial.read();

    }
} while (millis() - start < ms);
```

}

Comment: how does GPRS communicates to web server?